# Unable to run TensorFlow | Load images example (process_path error)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to run the following tutorial from TF: [Load images](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images).

I am running the *second method* (**Using tf.data for finer control**).

The provided tutorial runs fine up to using `Dataset.map` to "create a dataset of image, label pairs". Here, TF provides the following function to utilize `Dataset.map`:

```py
def get_label(file_path):
  # convert the path to a list of path components
  parts = tf.strings.split(file_path, os.path.sep)
  # The second to last is the class-directory
  one_hot = parts[-2] == class_names
  # Integer encode the label
  return tf.argmax(one_hot)

def decode_img(img):
  # convert the compressed string to a 3D uint8 tensor
  img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img, channels=3)
  # resize the image to the desired size
  return tf.image.resize(img, [img_height, img_width])

def process_path(file_path):
  label = get_label(file_path)
  # load the raw data from the file as a string
  img = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
  img = decode_img(img)
  return img, label
```

When I run the example, I get the following error:

```py
train_ds = train_ds.map(process_path, num_parallel_calls = AUTOTUNE)

TypeError: Value passted to parameter 'input'  has DataType 'bool' not in list of allowed values: float32, float64...
```

> As it is coming straight from TF website tutorials, I am unsure of where I am going wrong. Any ideas? The data directory is structured verbatim (from the tutorial):

flowers_photos/
daisy/
dandelion/
roses/
sunflowers/
tulips/

### Update 1

Output from attempt of @nicolas-gervais answer:

```py
for image, label in train_ds.take(5):
  print("Image shape: ", image.numpy().shape)
  print("Label: ", label.numpy () )

Image shape: (180, 180, 3)
Label: [[1.0 0 0 0 0]]

Image shape: (180, 180, 3)
Label: [[0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]]

Image shape: (180, 180, 3)
Label: [[1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]

Image shape: (180, 180, 3)
Label: [[0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]]

Image shape: (180, 180, 3)
Label: [[0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]]
```

Should be something akin to:
`Image shape: (180, 180, 3)`

`Label: 4`

### Update 2

It appears the above does not conform well, causes model to fail:

```py
class_names = np.array(sorted([item.name for item in data_dir.glob('*') if item.name != "LICENSE.txt"]))
print(class_names)
['daisy' 'dandelion' 'roses' 'sunflowers' 'tulips']
print(len(class_names))
5
...
model.fit(train_ds,validation_data=val_ds,epochs=15)

InvalidArgumentError: Logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape[5,5] and labels shape [25]
```

Comment: You shouldn't update your question three times for completely unrelated issues after answers have solved your issue. This website isn't for 1 on 1 tutoring on whatever issues you're facing. It's for solving specific, minimal issues that will be useful to others in the future.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

### Update 3 (Final)

Discovered that tensorflow has an option to pass here, specifically to [tf.io.decode_png](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/decode_image).

```
tf.io.decode_png( contents, channels=0, dtype=tf.dtypes.uint8, name=None)
```

After changing dtype=tf.dtypes.uint16, there were no problems. Hope it helps anyone for the future.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you can't use argmax on boolean tensors. You can instead do the one hot encoding manually. Just make sure to define `n_classes`.

```
def get_label(file_path):
    parts = tf.strings.split(file_path, os.path.sep)
    bool_values = tf.equal(parts[-2], class_names)
    indices = tf.where(bool_values)
    one_hot = tf.one_hot(indices, depth=n_classes)
    return one_hot
```

Look at this, Tensorflow doesn't support argmax for boolean tensors:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.convert_to_tensor([True, False, False])

tf.argmax(x)
```

```
tf.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Could not find valid device for node.
Node:{{node ArgMax}}
All kernels registered for op ArgMax :
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_INT64]; output_type in [DT_INT64]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_INT64]; output_type in [DT_INT32]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_INT32]; output_type in [DT_INT64]
```

Comment: I don't know what version they used. The important thing is that you work your way around. Don't hesitate to let me know if you made it work

Comment: Hmm, it outputs the one_hot vice label. Also, causing model failure now.

Comment: Ok so there's still two problems. Use `.batch(4)` atnthe end of your tf.data.Dataset. Also please show your model. I'm not sure what's causing the other error